# Dummy variables in Neural Networks

Tags: r, neural-network, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I am attempting to create a neural network, however, I am having trouble finding documentation with regards to categorical data.

I have a variable in my dataset which is categorical with **11** levels.

I think I need to convert this variable, however, I'm not sure what to convert it to.

Do I need to create **11** dummy variable to indicate whether or not a value for my categorical variable occurred?

Comment: Yes, if you use `OHE (one hot encoding)`, you can use `feature hashing`, if you have many features, to reduce the number of dummy variables.

Comment: If that categorical variable is not ordinal, I would use one-hot encoding. If you are using python, see here for [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) or here for [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).